# Excel macro - check for a string in a cell, run a routine, move to the next row, do it again

Tags: vba, excel

I am not a Dev, but given I do use Excel, I have been tasked to create a looping macro that will check for a string ('Resource') in a cell and if it finds that string, then run a Copy and Paste code and then move to the next row. This starts at row 5 and runs continuously until row 199, but does not work on every row, hence the validation for the string Resource.

I have managed to create the macro for the Copy and Paste but it also has issues as I created it using the macro recorder and it only works on the row I actually did the recording on.

I am at a complete loss, can anyone help?

this is what I have so far

1. A New Resource name is added manually to the spreadsheet
2. the user clicks cell (C6) to focus the curser
3. the user clicks a macro button called 'Forecast for Future Project 1' to start the macro

On the button click the Macro will:

Interogate if cell to the left of current cell (B6) = 'Resource'

```
IF Yes, THEN  



Sub CP()

DO

Range("C6").Select
Selection.Copy
Application.Goto Reference:="ProjAdd"
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF('Current Project Utilisation'!R2C1:R62C1,RC1,'Current Project Utilisation'!R2C:R62C)+SUMIF('Future Project 1'!R2C1:R62C1,RC1,'Future Project 1'!R2C:R62C)"
Range("ProjAdd").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B6").Select

Loop Until ActiveCell.Address(0,0) = "$B$199"

End Sub
```

Move to cell under original active cell (C7) and Repeat the Macro until cell C199 is reached

If (B6) does not = 'Resource' then move to go to the cell under (C7) aand Repeat the Macro until cell C199 is reached

Refresh Worksheet to update data

Comment: The spreadsheet lists a column of resources (going down the sheet) against hours per week for that resource (listed across the sheet) The hours per week are calculated in each cell with the string =SUMIF('Current Project Utilisation'!$A$2:$A$62,$A6,'Current Project Utilisation'!C$2:C$62) From the originating point ($C$6), the macro needs to check if the cell to the immediate left ($B$6) contains the string 'Resource' (As not all rows in the list contain resources

Comment: If YES, it has to copy the contents of $C$6 and add it to itself (changing some of the string text at the same time) so it will now read =SUMIF('Current Project Utilisation'!$A$2:$A$62,$A6,'Current Project Utilisation'!K$2:K$62)+SUMIF('Future Project 1'!$A$2:$A$62,$A6,'Future Project 1'!K$2:K$62) It then copies the content of $C$6 to all cells to the end of the row (currently $BK$6) It then drops down to the next row ($C$7) and repeats the process, continuing until row $C$199 The 'ProjAdd' named cell is where I was doing my copying and pasting

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
Sub CopyPasteResource()

Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set CopyRange = Workbooks("YourWorkBookName").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:C199")

For Each Cell In CopyRange

    If InStr(1, Cell.Offset(0, -1).Text, "Resource") Then

        Cell.Copy

        'paste where you wish

    End If

Next Cell

End Sub
```

EDIT: Or do you want to loop through B6:B199 and then C6:199? I'm not entirely clear on the aim.

Comment: The spreadsheet lists a column of resources (going down the sheet) against hours per week for that resource (listed across the sheet) 

The hours per week are calculated in each cell with the string =SUMIF('Current Project Utilisation'!$A$2:$A$62,$A6,'Current Project Utilisation'!C$2:C$62)

From the originating point ($C$6), the macro needs to check if the cell to the immediate left ($B$6) contains the string 'Resource' (As not all rows in the list contain resources)

Comment: If YES, it has to copy the contents of $C$6 and add it to itself (changing some of the string text at the same time) so it will now read =SUMIF('Current Project Utilisation'!$A$2:$A$62,$A6,'Current Project Utilisation'!K$2:K$62)+SUMIF('Future Project 1'!$A$2:$A$62,$A6,'Future Project 1'!K$2:K$62)

It then copies the content of $C$6 to all cells to the end of the row (currently $BK$6)

It then drops down to the next row ($C$7) and repeats the process, continuing until row $C$199

The 'ProjAdd' named cell is where I was doing my copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Ah the old macro recorder, generating 90% extra code since 1997. I couldn't exactly figure out from your question what exactly is being copied and to where but this code will loop through rows 5 to 199, check if the value in column B = "Resource" and then set the corresponding value in column C, you should be able to modify for your needs but I think you definitely want a structure more like this than what the recorder generated for you..

```
public sub cp()

    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Current Project Utilisation")
    Dim i as int
    for iI = 5 to 199
        if(ws.cells(i, 2).value = "Resource") then
            ws.cells(i, 3).value = "what you're copying"
        end if
    next I
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cell range doesn't change you can do this for the looping part

```
Sub ResourceCheck()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ActiveSheet


Dim Resources() As Long, r As Long
ReDim Resources(5 To 199)

For r = 5 To 199
    If UCase(WS.Cells(r, 2).Value) = "RESOURCE" Then
        WS.Cells(r, 3).Value = "x"
    'Do copy paste part
    End If
Next r

Application.Calculate

End Sub
```

Can you add a sample of your data? It's a bit hard to see what you're referencing to and how the data relates to each other.
Also, where is the "Projadd" cell reference? And what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CP()

' I like to know what worksheet I'm on 
Dim ws as Worksheet
' if it's a dedicated worksheet use this
' Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
' Otherwise following your current code
Set ws = ActiveSheet

' I also like to grab all my data at once
Dim Data as Variant
Data = ws.Range("B6:B199")

' No need to focus the cursor
For row = 5 to 199
    ' No need to select any range
    ' Is this case-sensitive???
    If Data(row-4, 1) = "Resource" Then
        ' Copy C6??? Paste 'ProjAdd'
        ws.Cells(row, 3).Copy Range("ProjAdd")
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next

End Sub
```